Zarankiewicz’s conjecture
The Turán's brick factory problem asks for the minimum number of crossings in a drawing of a complete bipartite graph. A few years later, Zarankiewicz published a formula that provided a solution to Turán's problem. Unfortunately, the proof is incorrect. For the bipartite complete graph $K_{n,m}$, Zarankiewicz's formula is $$\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor.$$
It is known that this last number is achieved with the following drawing:

My question is: How is this formula deduced from the previous drawing?
The drawing is built placing $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ points in the negative $x$-axis and $\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil$ in the positive $x$-axis. The other $m$ points are placed similarly in the $y$-axis.

To make the notation a bit easier on us, let's begin by just saying that we put $a$ points on the positive $x$-axis, $b$ points on the negative $x$-axis, $c$ points on the positive $y$-axis, and $d$ points on the negative $y$-axis.
Then the number of crossings in the first quadrant is $\binom a2 \binom c2$: the two crossing edges need to have two different endpoints on the positive $x$-axis and two different endpoints on the positive $y$-axis, and once you choose those four endpoints, there is only one crossing pair of edges that can be formed. This reasoning also applies to the other three quadrants, giving us $\binom a2 \binom d2$, $\binom b2 \binom c2$, and $\binom b2 \binom d2$ crossings. The sum of these four products factors as $\left(\binom a2 + \binom b2\right)\left(\binom c2 + \binom d2\right)$.
Now we can look at the two factors more carefully.

If $n$ is even, then $a = b = \frac n2$, so $\binom a2 + \binom b2 = 2\binom{n/2}{2}$ or $\frac n2 \cdot \frac{n-2}{2}$.
If $n$ is odd, then $a = \frac{n+1}{2}$ and $b = \frac{n-1}{2}$, so $\binom a2 + \binom b2 = \frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{8} + \frac{(n-1)(n-3)}{8}$, which simplfiies to $\frac{n-1}{2} \cdot \frac{n-1}{2}$.

To write both of these with one expression, we notice that the first factor ($\frac n2$ if $n$ is even, and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ when $n$ is odd) is $\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$, while the second factor ($\frac{n-2}{2}$ if $n$ is even, and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ when $n$ is odd) is $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$. So we have $\binom a2 + \binom b2 = \lfloor \frac n2\rfloor \cdot \lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor$, regardless of the parity of $n$.
Similarly, $\binom c2 + \binom d2 = \lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor \cdot \lfloor \frac{m-1}2 \rfloor$, regardless of the parity of $m$, and multiplying these together gives us the final expression.

When you count the $\binom{a}{2}\cdot\binom{c}{2}$ crossings, the edge in the "extreme" (with the more positive x value) will not have any crossing, thus, your argument should be modified with something like $\binom{a-1}{2}\cdot\binom{c-1}{2}$?

We're not picking edges, we're picking vertices. The vertex with the most positive $x$-value is involved in the same number of crossings as any other vertex on the positive $x$-axis.

As I understood, there is one crossing if and only if the edges have 2 different endpoints in the $x$-axis and $y$-axis but, if we take the edge with endpoints (for example) the most positive $x$ coordinate and the most positive $y$-axis and the other edge with the second most positive $x$ and the second most positive $y$, those edges don't cross.

Again - we are choosing vertices, not edges. You have chosen the two vertices with the most positive $x$-coordinates, and the two vertices with the most positive $y$-coordinates. There are four possible edges these vertices define, and one pair of those edges cross.

In general, if you choose any two vertices on the same half of the $x$-axis, and any two vertices on the same half of the $y$-axis, then those four vertices induce a $K_{2,2}$ with one crossing. This does not change if your $K_{2,2}$ includes the "most extreme" top right edge.
